# How to statically link libmvec?

Tags: c++, linux, static-linking

I'm trying to build a self contained executable, which I can run on any/most linux host.

I know I can do that with containers, but for now I'm trying to just statically link my exe.

I compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++1y -fopenmp -Ofast -g -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -m64 -c <source>.cpp -MMD -MP -o <object>.o
```

And link with:

```
g++ -std=c++1y -fopenmp -Ofast -g -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -m64 <list of object files> <list of absolute path to static libs .a> -lpthread -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o exe
```

It used to work just fine, but I just discovered it now breaks on some hosts with

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmvec.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know if it's something in the code or system libraries update. I have tried (to no avail):

- removing `-fopenmp`
- adding `-lmvec -lm` to the linker

My `exe` is indeed statically linked: `ldd exe` says `not a dynamic executable`. But it insists on loading `libmvec.so` at runtime: `strace exe` says:

- execv
- a bunch of mmap
- open(ld-linux-x86-64.so), read it and close it
- open(ld.so.cache), stat, mmap, and close it
- open(libpthread.so), read, stat, mmap and close it
- open(libmvec.so) => *fail on hosts where it doesn't exist*
- [...]

As I understand [libmvec](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec) is an extension of libm, dealing with x86 vectorization, used by OpenMP.

So basically, **I'm asking if there is a way to make it work statically** - I see at least 3 solutions:

- disable its use - but that would probably mean performance loss, plus it is used even when I disable OpenMP
- statically link it, and somehow explain to the runtime that it then doesn't have to dynamically link to it since it's already linked.
- make it optional, i.e. dynamically select a slower code path if it's not available. This sounds complex but could in theory be possible.

Comment: libmvec is probably loaded by libm using dlopen

Comment: Even if the libmvec problem is solved I think you will have problems with the glibc version. You won't be able to run the exe on an OS older than the one on the build machine.

Comment: @Brahim: the OS are different, but it used to work just fine, plus glibc can also be statically linked. The only thing we can't overcome is kernel version and possibly missing system calls ?